# Eclipse neon "no staged files" error

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I am using Eclipse Neon for Github, to be able to push changes.

I already have a Github account and made a specific repository just for trying, but nothing ends up in the repository, though I follow guides and do exactly the same without getting any errors, but ending up with an empty Github repository (except for the Readme file that I created along with the repository at the website).

I've made several Java Projects with a simple `main` method, and a method for just writing a dummy message, simple, but doesn't exist in repository.
Then I right click the project, select **Team** -> **Share Project** and select:
**Repository: NewGit - /home/jannik/NewGit.git**, **working tree: /home/jannik/NewGit** and **Path within repository: dummy** and click my dummy project and press finish.

Now I right click my project again and choose **Remote** -> **Push** and choose the default option called **Configured remote repository** which says **origin: https://github.com/< my-github-account>/eclipseTest.git** which tells me that it links to my repository named eclipseTest (which I made on website).

I then press Next and press ***Add all Branches spec** and clicks next, and then Finish. I then get a dialog saying that Master and NewGit branches are up-to-date, though my dummy project is missing.

If I try the **Commit** option in Eclipse, I get an error saying that there're no staged files

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make any commit?

Comment: When I try to commit, I get an error saying that there're no staged files

Comment: Since your issue was not just related to the IDE, I suggest to get a little knowledge of how git works and how it is different form other VCS. You can have a look at [Pro Git](https://progit.org). It is a very good resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before being able to push anywhere, you need to add and commit first.

See "[EGit/User Guide/Commit](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide)" for adding and committing.

Its [Track Changes](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Track_Changes) sections shows how to add files to the index.

> Click `Team > Add to Index` on the project node. (This menu item is named `Add` on older versions of Egit.)

Then:

> `Click Team > Commit` in the project context menu.

Finally, you can push.

Answer (score 1):

go to >Theam > commit >
 you will get the changed list of files and in those you can move changed files to **staged changes** block and then commit.

See this image you can find the solution:

[image]

Comment: What is "Theam"? Did you mean *Team*?